# Why doesn't the color change in my code dynamically each time I click the button?

Tags: javascript, dom

The function only seems to execute once each time I click, then I'd have to refresh the page and click the button again to get a different background color. Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm a beginner and any help would be appreciated.

```
let bod = document.getElementById("bod");
let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
let btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  switch (random) {
    case 1:
      bod.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFF00";
      break;
    case 2:
      bod.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
      break;

    case 3:
      bod.style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00";
      break;

    case 4:
      bod.style.backgroundColor = "#0000FF";
      break;

    case 5:
      bod.style.backgroundColor = "#808080";
      break;

    case 6:
      bod.style.backgroundColor = "#A020F0.";

      break;

    case 7:
      bod.style.backgroundColor = "#FFC0CB";
      break;

    case 8:
      bod.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
      break;

    case 9:
      bod.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
      break;

    case 10:
      bod.style.backgroundColor = "#FFD700";
      break;

    default:
    // code block
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you're generating random number only 1 time during the very start, you need to generate it every time:

```js
let bod = document.getElementById("bod");
let btn = document.getElementById("btn")

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10); // <-- HERE
  switch(random) {
    case 0: bod.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFF00"; break;
    case 1: bod.style.backgroundColor = "#000000"; break;
    case 2: bod.style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00"; break;
    case 3: bod.style.backgroundColor = "#0000FF"; break;
    case 4: bod.style.backgroundColor = "#808080"; break;
    case 5: bod.style.backgroundColor = "#A020F0"; break;
    case 6: bod.style.backgroundColor = "#FFC0CB"; break;
    case 7: bod.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000"; break;
    case 8: bod.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF"; break;
    case 9: bod.style.backgroundColor = "#FFD700"; break;
 }
});
```

```html
<div id="bod">test</div>
<button id="btn">button</button>
```

update: don't forget that floor(random*10) will generate number from 0 to 9

Comment: Thank you! This answer was very insightful.